# Loop not finding elements after going to new page.StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: c#, selenium

```
        List<IWebElement> shittyBiz = new List<IWebElement>();
        var myEles = driverGC.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.search-result"));
        for (int i = 0;i<=1000;i++){
            myEles = driverGC.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.search-result"));
            foreach (IWebElement business in myEles)
            {
                driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                var starRating = " ";
                try
                {
                    starRating = business.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.biz-rating > div.i-stars")).GetAttribute("title");
                }
                catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No stars");
                    continue;
                }
                starRating = Regex.Replace(starRating, @"[A-Za-z\s]", string.Empty);
                float stars = float.Parse(starRating);
                MessageBox.Show(stars.ToString());

                if (stars <= 3)
                {
                    //shittyBiz.Add(starRating);
                    MessageBox.Show("Shitty");
                    driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    var bizName = business.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".biz-name"));
                    MessageBox.Show(bizName.Text);
                    shittyBiz.Add(bizName);
                    var bizLocation = business.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".secondary-attributes"));
                    MessageBox.Show(bizLocation.Text);
                    shittyBiz.Add(bizLocation);
                }
                else
                {
                    driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    MessageBox.Show("Too good");
                }

            }
            try
            {
                driverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.arrange_unit > a.u-decoration-none")).Click();
                continue;
            }
            catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No more pages");
                return;
                //driverGC.Quit();
            }
        }
```

I can get the program to run fine the first time, but after it uses the try at the end, to go to the next page, i get the StaleElementReferenceException error almost immediately on the starRating in the first try. I have tried everything that I can think of, but not sure why it is throwing me that error.

Answer (score 0):

When the DOM is refreshed or changed the driver loses all the elements it previously located. After moving to the new page `myEles` is not valid any more and that's why you get `StaleElementReferenceException` on `business` when you trying to use it to locate another element. The solution is to locate `myEles` each iteration and keep the location using indexes with `for` loop

```
int size = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    var myEles = driverGC.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.search-result"));
    size = myEles.Count();

    driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    var starRating = " ";
    try
    {
        starRating = myEles[i].FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.biz-rating > div.i-stars")).GetAttribute("title");
    }

    //...

    // and don't forget to go back
    driver.Navigate().Back();
}
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this did not work It does not give me a different value for each element and i still get stale error when i go to next page.

Comment: @JustinKowalsky can you post your new code? and where exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: Not sure exactly how to post the code correctly, so heres the paste bin. http://pastebin.com/jJk1hWCw When i run the code, it exectutes fine the first time. Then gets to line 88, clicks the next button and then goes back to the top where i catch the StaleElementReferenceException right away and then it will repeat the error over and over again, but contiunes to go through and go to the next page.

Comment: @JustinKowalsky You didn't change it. The `for` loop in my answer should replace the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Okay, so it no longer gives me the error, but it also does not continue getting the elements when it goes to a new page. It just sits there and does nothing.

Comment: @JustinKowalsky Perheps the new page doesn't have this elements. Try to debug it and see exactly what is happening.